# Split rows to columns by certain number

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have the following rows in the table:

```
dates
------------
"2021-01-02"
"2021-01-03"
"2021-01-11"
"2021-01-14"
...
```

I know that these rows present date ranges.
So, the first row is a range start, next row is a range end. Next row is a range start again and etc (*the numbers of rows* mod 2 = 0).

Is there a way to select such table as:

```
range_start  | range_end
-------------+-------------
"2021-01-02"   "2021-01-03"
"2021-01-11"   "2021-01-14"
...            ...
```

?

PostgreSQL version is 10.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation with `row_number()`:

```
select min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by ceiling(seqnum / 2.0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I also hope that some sort of window functions will allow just to select first record in grouped set (for range start) and second (last) record in grouped set (for range end).

Comment: @Andrey . . . I'm not sure what your comment means.  This does what the question is asking for.  There is no need for additional window functions.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
WITH ordered_table AS (
  SELECT
    dates,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY dates) AS creation_order
  FROM your_table
)
SELECT
  t1.dates AS range_start,
  t2.dates AS range_end
FROM
  ordered_table t1
INNER JOIN ordered_table t2 ON t2.creation_order = t1.creation_order + 1
WHERE (t1.creation_order % 2) = 1 -- counting from 1
```

For more details:

- [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-with.html) in PG
- [row_number](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-window.html) in PG